# Can I add a button to start and stop the transition by using JS or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, css

Is it possible to add a button to control(start/stop) the transition? This is the HTML code:

https://jsfiddle.net/jxgskgp6/

```css
@keyframes roundandround {
  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.scene {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.ball {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: roundandround 7.5s 1.3s infinite linear;
}

.ball .ring {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 6px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 0.75s forwards ease-in-out;
}

.ring:nth-child(1) {
  color: #8df435;
  transform: rotateY(4deg);
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.ring:nth-child(2) {
  color: #a8e526;
  transform: rotateY(8deg);
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.ring:nth-child(3) {
  color: #c2d11c;
  transform: rotateY(12deg);
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.ring:nth-child(4) {
  color: #c8cb1b;
  transform: rotateY(16deg);
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.ring:nth-child(5) {
  color: #deb21a;
  transform: rotateY(20deg);
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.ring:nth-child(6) {
  color: #ef9621;
  transform: rotateY(24deg);
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.ring:nth-child(7) {
  color: #f29122;
  transform: rotateY(28deg);
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.ring:nth-child(8) {
  color: #fb7430;
  transform: rotateY(32deg);
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.ring:nth-child(9) {
  color: #fe5944;
  transform: rotateY(36deg);
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.ring:nth-child(10) {
  color: #fe5548;
  transform: rotateY(40deg);
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.ring:nth-child(11) {
  color: #f83d61;
  transform: rotateY(44deg);
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.ring:nth-child(12) {
  color: #ec2b7d;
  transform: rotateY(48deg);
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}

.ring:nth-child(13) {
  color: #e82983;
  transform: rotateY(52deg);
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.ring:nth-child(14) {
  color: #d41e9f;
  transform: rotateY(56deg);
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.ring:nth-child(15) {
  color: #bd1aba;
  transform: rotateY(60deg);
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.ring:nth-child(16) {
  color: #b81ac0;
  transform: rotateY(64deg);
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.ring:nth-child(17) {
  color: #9c1fd7;
  transform: rotateY(68deg);
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.ring:nth-child(18) {
  color: #802aea;
  transform: rotateY(72deg);
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.ring:nth-child(19) {
  color: #7a2dee;
  transform: rotateY(76deg);
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.ring:nth-child(20) {
  color: #5f40f9;
  transform: rotateY(80deg);
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.ring:nth-child(21) {
  color: #4657fe;
  transform: rotateY(84deg);
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.ring:nth-child(22) {
  color: #425cfe;
  transform: rotateY(88deg);
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.ring:nth-child(23) {
  color: #2f77fb;
  transform: rotateY(92deg);
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="ball">
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
      <li class="ring"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this, where you add this CSS rule, button and script.

What it does is simply adds/removes the `stop` class to your `ball` element, which toggles the animations play state.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxgskgp6/1/)

HTML

```
<button>Start/Stop</button>
```

CSS

```
.ball.stop {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
  var btn = document.querySelector('button');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    ball.classList.toggle('stop');
  })
})
```